# Create sequence between certain values across two vectors

Tags: r, vector, sequence, between

I am currently trying to create sequences between values of different vectors that do not have the same length.

Imagine I have the two following vectors a and b:

```
a<-c(1, 8, 14, 34, 46, 55)
b<-c(3, 6, 12, 13, 18, 42, 49, 50, 57, 200)
```

I would like to generate a third vector that shows the sequences between the values of `a` and the next highest value of `b` (here: `1:3` as `1,2,3`;  `8:12` as `8,9,10,11,12`; `14:18` as `14,15,16,17,18` and so on until finally `55:57` as `55,56,57`).

Using `mapply` did not yield the desired results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `findInterval` to subset the 'b' based on the value of 'a' and then with `Map` get the corresponding sequence (`:=`) between the elements of the 'a' and the subset elements of 'b'

```
Map(`:`, a, b[findInterval(a, b) + 1])
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1]  8  9 10 11 12

#[[3]]
#[1] 14 15 16 17 18

#[[4]]
#[1] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42

#[[5]]
#[1] 46 47 48 49

#[[6]]
#[1] 55 56 57
```

Comment: Hello, I have a late additional enquiry: the code has worked just fine for 95% of my data. However, in some cases (input data of same structure as before), the code results in a "Error in .Primitive(":")(dots[[1L]][[26L]], dots[[2L]][[26L]]) : 
  NA/NaN Argument" output. I can't see why. "NA/NaN Argument" seems to say that there is no data to process, but I have checked the previous steps manually. Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: @sant Could you check if tehre are cases where only NA/NaN.  IN that case, use a `if/else` condition to take care of that

Comment: Yes, there are whole lists that don't work. Take for example a and b from the initial post: I run two similarly structured  lists, and the result its the NA/NaN-Error. Can you specify in what way you would include an if/else condition? Thank you!

Comment: @sant  Could you update with a small reproducible example so that we will be in the same page

Answer (score 6):

```
lapply(a, function(x) x:b[b>x][1])
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1]  8  9 10 11 12

#[[3]]
#[1] 14 15 16 17 18

#[[4]]
#[1] 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42

#[[5]]
#[1] 46 47 48 49

#[[6]]
#[1] 55 56 57
```

Comment: nice answer, what is the meaning of '[1]' at the end?